# Nginx and uwsgi timeouts

Tags: nginx, timeout, uwsgi

I have nginx serving a django app powered by uwsgi. Occasionally I am getting 504's and want to increase the timeout. When using the nginx uwsgi module, do I need to use a special param to account for possible timeouts, or can I use a standard one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I view source and find uwsgi_connect_timeout,uwsgi_send_timeout,uwsgi_read_timeout params and it works. But default is 60 second... I think this is enough.